# Error en sitio, Dominio se cambia por IP

Tags: iis, windows-server-2016

Tengo un problema con un servidor en la nube, tengo alojada mi pagina web y tengo contratado un Dominio, tambien tengo una direccion IP publica, los DNS del dominio apuntan a IP publica y todo funciona hasta ahi, pero al ingresar el dominio desde otra pc me cambia todo mi dominio y lo sustituye por mi IP publica, puedo ver mi pagina sin problemas y desde dentro del servidor ingresando igual me mantiene el dominio sin cambiarlo, que configuracion me hace falta para poder evitar que se sustituya mi dominio por la IP?

PD: tengo los bindings de mi sitio apuntando al dominio en IIS

Comment: si en tu dominio tu A record apunta únicamente a tu ip, mas bien tienes que revisar si dentro de el iis no hay alguna redirección, o dentro de tu pagina, alguna validación que te mande por la ip.

Comment: En las zonas del DNS estan apuntando a mi dominio, dentro de la pagina igual estan a puntando al dominio, no a la IP, el binding de los sitios apuntan al mismo sitio, lo que no se es porque dentro del servidor puedo ver el dominio sin problemas y por fuera ya no